# UISegmentedViewController cutting off view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am running into a weird problem. I am using a UISegmentedControl to switch between two views. When the UISegmentedViewController comes on screen, the default view(view1) is loaded.View1 looks exactly as it should, but when I click the UISegmentedControl to change views, view2 does not look properly and is cut off. When I switch back to view1 now it also exhibits the same behavior. I am attaching the code I am using for this UISegmentedViewController below - I found it in a SO post. I will attach pictures for clarity:

Edit: Also, the last tableview cell in the Courses section cannot be properly scrolled to. Why is the view getting cut off?

[image: Initial Loadup]

[image: After clicking on the Professors segment]

[image: Going back to the initial Courses segment]

Code:

```
//
//  PCFSegmentedRateViewController.m
//  Purdue Course Sniper
//
//  Created by Kamran Pirwani on 2/5/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Kamran Pirwani. All rights reserved.
//

#import "PCFSegmentedRateViewController.h"

@interface PCFSegmentedRateViewController ()
// Array of view controllers to switch between
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *allViewControllers;

// Currently selected view controller
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *currentViewController;

@end


@implementation PCFSegmentedRateViewController
@synthesize classRating,professorRating,segmentedControl;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    classRating = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ClassRate"];
    professorRating = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Professor"];
    // Add A and B view controllers to the array
    self.allViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:classRating, professorRating, nil];
    [self cycleFromViewController:self.currentViewController toViewController:[self.allViewControllers objectAtIndex:self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex]];
}

#pragma mark - View controller switching and saving

- (void)cycleFromViewController:(UIViewController*)oldVC toViewController:(UIViewController*)newVC {

    // Do nothing if we are attempting to swap to the same view controller
    if (newVC == oldVC) return;

    // Check the newVC is non-nil otherwise expect a crash: NSInvalidArgumentException
    if (newVC) {

        // Set the new view controller frame (in this case to be the size of the available screen bounds)
        // Calulate any other frame animations here (e.g. for the oldVC)
        newVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMinY(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds));

        // Check the oldVC is non-nil otherwise expect a crash: NSInvalidArgumentException
    if (oldVC) {

            // Start both the view controller transitions
            [oldVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
            [self addChildViewController:newVC];

            // Swap the view controllers
            // No frame animations in this code but these would go in the animations block
            [self transitionFromViewController:oldVC
                              toViewController:newVC
                                      duration:0.25
                                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
                                    animations:^{}
                                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                        // Finish both the view controller transitions
                                        [oldVC removeFromParentViewController];
                                        [newVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                                        // Store a reference to the current controller
                                        self.currentViewController = newVC;
                                    }];

        } else {

            // Otherwise we are adding a view controller for the first time
            // Start the view controller transition
            [self addChildViewController:newVC];

            // Add the new view controller view to the ciew hierarchy
            [self.view addSubview:newVC.view];

            // End the view controller transition
            [newVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

            // Store a reference to the current controller
            self.currentViewController = newVC;
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {

    NSUInteger index = sender.selectedSegmentIndex;

    if (UISegmentedControlNoSegment != index) {
        UIViewController *incomingViewController = [self.allViewControllers objectAtIndex:index];
        [self cycleFromViewController:self.currentViewController toViewController:incomingViewController];
    }

}
@end
```

Comment: Awesome to see SO will accept this much graphic size. Holy good mother.

Comment: So you need to log the Frames of the views after the switch. Probably the view you show is a subview of another view, and the frames don't match, or the springs and struts (or autolayout) is not set right. This gets tedious to track down but is surely the root problem. I always use a UIViewController base class with some helper debug methods that lets me dump out subviews and superviews when called - frames, resize masks, isHidden, etc - these come in quite handy when faced with a problem like yours.

Comment: Hey, when I changed the springs and struts for the UITableView it works fine. The last cell is still getting cut off though. Any suggestions for that?